# python windows os.stat three dots fold failed

Tags: python, windows

For example, you have a file `a.txt` in  `G:\1...` (from `linux`,or `md G:\1...`):

```
os.listdir(r'G:\1...')  
[]  
os.stat(r'G:\1...')  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
WindowsError: [Error 2] : 'G:\\1...'
```

I want to know how can I get information of such fold (also I can't `os.stat(r'G:\1...\file')` when it copied from linux.

Comment: Windows does a lot of preprocessing on paths before passing them to the I/O manager in the kernel, e.g. to resolve "." and ".." components. Part of this processing is to implement old MS-DOS rules, like removing trailing spaces and dots. You can bypass this path processing by using a fully-qualified, backslash delimitted (forward slash doesn't work, even if it appears to work in some cases), Unicode path that's prefixed by ``\\?\``, e.g. ``u"\\\\?\\G:\\..."``.

Comment: That said, normal path processing only removes trailing dots from the last component in the path, so `os.stat(r'G:\1...\file')` should work. A similar example works fine for me.

Comment: `os.stat(u'\\\\?\\G:\\1...')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=1482739662L, st_mtime=1482739662L, st_ctime=1482739662L
)  `

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! It really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @eryksun 's comment:

> normal path processing only removes trailing dots from the last component in the path

```
os.stat(u'\\\\?\\G:\\1...') 
nt.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=1482739662L, st_mtime=1482739662L, st_ctime=1482739662L)
```

BTW: any know detail preprocess of path in windows and post it will be appreciated.